# Getting Invalid Float in Fortran and I'm not sure why

Tags: fortran

So I'm getting an invalid float error that's causing my code to crash from the following subroutine. The subroutine sums together my distribution function over angle and energy (so I just have a distribution in radius), then I compute my average optical depth, and then I look for the radial zone where that optical depth crosses 2/3. The code is designed to be run over multiple time steps, and in this particular simulation it had run through 49 time steps and then crashed on the 50th, which is confusing me even more.

```
subroutine SAPass(state, step)

use state_vector_module
use boltztran_memory_module, only: fe, trmfpe
use boltztran_parameter_module 
use units_module

implicit none

real, dimension(102) :: Fse
real, dimension(102,8) :: taue
real, dimension(102) :: Te
inetger :: cycsav = -1
integer :: nsze

call opdep(trmfpe, taue)

Fse = 0.
do i=1,102
do j=1,4
do k=1,8
  Fse(i) = Fse(i) + fe(i,j,k)
end do
end do
end do

do i=1,102
do j=1,4
do k=1,8
  if (Fse(i).eq.0.) then
    Te(i) = 0.
  else
    Te(i) = Te(i) + (fe(i,j,k)*taue(i,k))/Fse(i)
  end if
end do
end do
end do 

write(*,*) Te    !debug check to look for where the error is happening

nsze = 1
do i=1,101
  if(Te(i).eq.(2./3.)) then    ! This is the line the invalid float error is reported on. 
    nsze = i
  else if((Te(i).gt.(2./3.)).and.(Te(i+1).lt.(2./3.))) then
    nsze = i
  end if
end do

if(step.eq.cycsav) then
  continue
else
  cycsav = istep
  call tauwrite(taue,step,1)
  open(17,name="NSZones.dat",status="unknown",position="append")
  write(17,i5) nsze
  close(17)
end if
```

On time step 50 the code crashes and I get the following error:

```
forrtl: error (65): floating invalid
```

And it references the specified line in the code. When I look at the print outs for Te during time step 50 the entry for i=4 is a 'NaN' and I can't figure out what in the code could be causing this to become a NaN. The distribution function numbers all look normal for that time step and zone.

Comment: Can you post the whole code we can run? Including all declarations, `implicit none`, `program` and `end program`.

Comment: If `Fse(i)` is close to zero, that could cause `Te(i)` to be NaN.  BTW, that `(Te(i).eq.(2./3.))` test is not likely to work as you expect, since 2/3 cannot be represented exactly in binary.

Comment: I added the rest of the code as requested, but this is a small subroutine in a very large sprawling code, posting all of the subroutines that feed in and out of this would not really be feasible.

Comment: as a debugging trick `NaN` is not equal to itself, so you can put `if(te(i).ne.te(i))write(*,*)i,j,k,Te(i),fe(i,j,k),taue(i,k),Fse(i)` in the first loop.

Comment: See [mcve] how to create a good example code from your subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You use

`Fse(i).eq.0.`

`Te(i).eq.(2./3.)`

It is a very bad idea to compare two floating point numbers for equality. You are probably dividing by an almost-zero in

```
Te(i) = Te(i) + (fe(i,j,k)*taue(i,k))/Fse(i)
```

and that results in an error.

It is impossible to say more, because we can't see what `fe` is and which values it has nor which values `taue` has.